# Window is not being moved until clicked

Tags: c#, winapi, window, dllimport, user32

I have an application in which I'd like to control the behavior of an external window. I'm trying to set this window size and position by calling:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

private void DoOnControlSize(IntPtr wind) 
{
    if (wind != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MoveWindow(wind, 0, 0, 620, 480, true);
    }
}
```

Window handle is found correctly and `MoveWindow` works but the size and position is changed only after clicking on this external window and calling the method again.

This controlled window is borderless and with no style.

Is there a way to imitate that click by the code?

I've tried WinAPI `SetFocus`, `SetForegroundWindow` and `SetActiveWindow` methods but nothing works.

Comment: perhaps you need to call MoveWindow method call in side of the other forms form.Show method or form.Create method..

Comment: The external window is out of reach because it's a window of an external application and I can't control its code.

Comment: You say "`MoveWindow` works." What does that mean? Have you checked the return code to make sure it returns `True`? If it returns `False` you need to check the last error. And why do you have the managed prototype for `SetWindowPos` when you're calling `MoveWindow`?

Comment: I fixed wrong `SetWindowPos` - sorry. In every situation: when window changes its size and when not `MoveWindow` returns `True`.

Comment: After using [Window Detective](http://windowdetective.sourceforge.net/) I've noticed that clicking on external window sends `WM_NCACTIVATE`, `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` and `WM_ACTIVATE` messages to the handle but after sending them by the code using `PostMessage` or `SendMessage` still nothing happens. Somehow window is deaf for any messages until its being clicked manually.